# Understanding the on() method in sockets - PHP (REACT/ZMQ)

Tags: php, sockets, zeromq

I did my best looking for a documentation of the `on()` method when applied on socket object (ZMQSocket).

```
$loop=.....// an even loop object

$context =  new \React\ZMQ\Context($loop);

$pull = $context->getSocket(\ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL);

$pull->bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:5555');

$pull->on('message', array($newArticlePusher, 'onNewArticle'));
```

I don't find it in the [list](http://php.net/manual/en/class.zmqsocket.php) of methods of ZMQSocket. What is it exactly? What is its signature?

Your usual help is greatly appreciated. Any link or docs explaining this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That function does not belong to `ZMQSocket` class it belong to the framework you're using, `React`. React is simply "binding" the ZMQSocket class.

In web sockets there are 4 main action/methods.

1. On Message
2. On Error
3. On Close
4. On Open

The one your asking about `on('message'...` is the method/action On Message. This is when you receive incoming socket messages and the second parameter `array($newArticlePusher, 'onNewArticle')` is the action you're going to take (The response to the client socket).

There is really not documentation for it. I would recommend you to start learning websockets in java as they have one of the best documentations out there for websockets, [here](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/HomeWebsocket/WebsocketHome.html).

Comment: I understand sir, well explained. I just want to take more of your time please if possible. Where can I find details of this function under React? Here is my situation: I already implemented 3 classes with 3 callbacks: `$newArticlePusher` with `onNewArticle`, `$followPusher` with `onFollow` and  `$unfollowPusher` with `onUnfollow`. My goal is to merge the 3 functionnalities in one class containing the 3 actions and then create one `on('message')` line. I just don't know how to deal with second argument and its array(s.). Should i ask separate question?

Comment: The best advice I can give you is to just look at the comments for each of the functions you're going to use from React (If they even used comments). I've search before for documentation and they have exactly none. You really don't have to use an array for the second argument, you can use anonymous functions. Have a look at the example they provided in their repository https://github.com/reactphp/zmq

Comment: Thank you again Sir, very appreciated :-)

Comment: I gave it a little thought and it seems that my approach is not efficient. Why to create one Pusher class with 3 methods and inject these 3 methods in the argument of `on()` while I only have one socket? It will not recognize which one to execute. I will use one method in one Pusher class with a `switch(n)` statement +  I will add a field `n` in the data sent over the socket for wihch I will perform the switch. In, fact, REACT people are ok when they limited the second argument to one function. I hope I am not wrong

Comment: My second approach works perfectly. If anyone is seeking details and code I will be happy to share.

Comment: @whitelettersinblankpapers yes please share the it

Answer (score 0):

There is also few monitoring actions which could be useful.

NodeJS implementaion: https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node#monitoring

zmq doc: http://api.zeromq.org/4-2:zmq-socket-monitor

This actions require to start monitoring.